# How do I call a function with parameters stored in an array?

Tags: php

I have an array of functions:

```
$functions = array(
    "sum" => function($v1, $v2) {
        $s = $v1 + $v2;
        return $s;
    }
);
```

Now, I'm confused about how to call this specific function -

```
echo $functions["sum"](1,2); //suppose to echo 3
```

doesn't work.

Comment: How does it "not work"?  Do you see any errors?  What PHP version are you using?  You need 5.3+ for this to work.

Comment: You edited your question with the missing semi-colon, which was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
<?php

$functions = array(
    "sum" => function($v1, $v2) {
        $s = $v1 + $v2;
        return $s;
    });

echo $functions['sum'](1,2); //"prints" 3
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/99122)

Comment: Other than formatting, this is EXACTLY what the OP posted.

Comment: He added a semicolon. Would have been more helpful to mention that explicitly rather than just hoping the OP would notice...

Comment: The error is obviously the missing semi-colon. I tested OP's code and it output `3` in my test, so OP is not showing us exact usage, even after doing an edit in his/her question.

Comment: Nope fred, I think it is related to the function array referencing thing..

Comment: I tested OP's code with the missing semi-colon at the end of the echo, and it printed `3` @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: The OP edited the question with the added semi-colon during the 5 minute grace period, therefore the original missing semi-colon for the echo isn't showing in the edit. @MarcB - I didn't dream this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

- The OP added the missing semi-colon in question just now, which is the obvious problem.
- The OP edited the question with the added semi-colon during the 5 minute grace period, therefore the original missing semi-colon isn't showing in the edit. (*I know what I saw*)

---

#### Tested and working

The error is the missing semi-colon at the end of

```
echo $functions["sum"](1,2)
```

make it:

```
echo $functions["sum"](1,2);
```

which I tested to output as `3`

---

Fully tested and working code, output `3` - adding missing semi-colon at the end of the echo.

```
<?php

$functions = array(
    "sum" => function($v1, $v2) {
        $s = $v1 + $v2;
        return $s;
    }
);

echo $functions["sum"](1,2); // echos 3
```

---

This one prints `10`

```
<?php

$functions = array(
    "sum" => function($v1, $v2) {
        $s = $v1 + $v2;
        return $s;
    }
);

echo $functions["sum"](1,9); // prints 10
```

---

**Multiplication method** using `2` and `9` outputs `18`

```
<?php
$functions = array(
    "sum" => function($v1, $v2) {
        $s = $v1 * $v2;
        return $s;
    }
);

echo $functions["sum"](2,9); // echos 18
```

Comment: downvoter, explanation perhaps? The OP changed the question/code and it's obvious.

Comment: A downvote deserves an explanation. Not doing so, doesn't clarify nor does it justify the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here:

```
php > $funcs = array('sum' => function($v1, $v2) { return $v1 + $v2; });
php > echo $funcs['sum'](1,2);
3
php > echo $funcs['sum']('foo','bar');
0
```